# Can one include an if-statement in a method in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, if-statement, methods

I have defined a class for a peach tree as a part of an assignment. I was wondering if I could include an if statement in one of my methods to make the tree die after 60 years. This is my code:

```
class Tree
  def initialize(color="green", fruit="peaches", age=0, peaches_amount=0)
    @color = color
    @fruit = fruit
    @age = age
  end

#age increases by one year every year
  def the_age
    @age += 1
    return @age
  end

#yield of peaches increases by 5 peaches every year
  def peaches
    @peaches_amount += 5
    return @peaches_amount
  end

  def death
    if age <60 return "I am dead"
    else 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Of course you can. What is the problem with your code?

Comment: Where else would you put it?

Comment: what would I include in the else statement?

Comment: With the caveat that  your logic is backwards, and would be canonically expressed as `def death; return "I am dead" if age > 60; end` or similar.

Comment: @user2759592 What do want to return if it's not dead?

Comment: We can't answer a question about what your app does because we aren't developing your app. Personally I would have a `dead?` method that returns true if the age > 60 and false otherwise. Then use that method wherever you need to check if a tree is dead.

Comment: Can you show how you want to use the class? What should death be? Is it the question, if the tree is dead? Then use `death?`. Or should it be a method to end the trees life? Then you need a variable `@died` and you may use it.

Comment: It is unclear what's your problem. Maybe you could try the question in http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try:

```
tree = Tree.new
tree.peaches
```

- You get an error `undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass`.
- You never define `@peaches_amount`.
- You never define `age`.

In your definition, you are dead if you are younger then 60. I think you must reverse your check.

You may also check in `peaches` if you are already dead.

See my example:

```
class Tree
    def initialize(color="green", fruit="peaches", age=0, peaches_amount=0)
            @color = color
            @fruit = fruit
            @age = age
            @peaches_amount = peaches_amount
            @dead = false
    end
    #age increases by one year every year
    def the_age
           @age += 1
           if @age == 60 
             @dead = true
             puts "I died"
           end
          return @age
    end
    #yield of peaches increases by 5 peaches every year
    def peaches
      if @dead
        return 0 
      else
        return 5 * @age
       end
    end

    def dead?
      if @dead
        return "I am dead"
      else 
        return "I am living"
      end
    end
  end

tree = Tree.new
puts "%i Peaches after %i years" % [ tree.peaches, tree.age ]
30.times{ tree.the_age }
puts "%i Peaches after %i years" % [ tree.peaches, tree.age ]
30.times{ tree.the_age }
puts "%i Peaches after %i years" % [ tree.peaches, tree.age ]
```

The output:

```
0 Peaches after 0 years
150 Peaches after 30 years
I died
0 Peaches after 60 years
```

To give you a real answer, you should define what you want to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Check your syntax. Do not place `return "I am dead"` on the same line as the condition!

```
if @age > 60
 "I am dead"
end
```

You can also do:

```
"I am dead" if @ge > 60
```

Also, you do not need explicit returns in Ruby, at least in this case because the result of the last evaluated statement is the return value of the method.

A nice thing to know: You can use `ruby -c my_script.rb` to check if you have syntax errors. Or a good IDE.

This is Ruby 101, so I suggest you read some good books or follow some tutorials, there's plenty out there.